# Tornado based XMPP server and client

Tags: xmpp, chat, tornado, ejabberd, strophe

We are working on a chatting based website. After doing an extensive literature review we shorted to use Tornado as our web server, socket.io as client side javascript.

We are now in a process to scale up our application to serve approximately 50,000 users at a time. So, I would like to ask if Ejabberd can fit in our architecture (agreeing to the fact that we are open to changes, which change our current implementation drastically, provided it is worth it) or is there any other technology stack for scaling up the same.

Our focus is one one to one user chatting.

Answer (score 3):

In short yes it can, with one small drawback:

XMPP's standard way of communicating with web clients is [BOSH](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html). BOSH is a long-polling solution that works over HTTP. Websockets are not yet part of the picture, although there exists a [draft proposal](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-moffitt-xmpp-over-websocket-00).

That said, the javascript library that is most commonly used for web clients is [Strophe](http://strophe.im/). There exists an (experimental?) plugin for both [ejabberd](https://github.com/superfeedr/ejabberd-websockets) and [strophe](https://github.com/superfeedr/strophejs) where communication happens through websockets. The plugin is described [here](http://blog.superfeedr.com/xmpp-over-websockets/).